# Create PDF file from HTML text React

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

I am beginner in react-redux.

I trying create a function like exporting a html text to pdf with Javascript and it works with html, but when I apply it to react component, it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.pdfToHTML=this.pdfToHTML.bind(this);
  }

  pdfToHTML(){
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
    var source = $('#HTMLtoPDF')[0];
    var specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
        return true
      }
    };

    var margins = {
      top: 50,
      left: 60,
      width: 545
    };

    pdf.fromHTML (
      source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
      , margins.left // x coord
      , margins.top // y coord
      , {
          'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
          , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        },
      function (dispose) {
        // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
        // this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('html2pdf.pdf');
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div classID="HTMLtoPDF">
          <center>
            <h2>HTML to PDF</h2>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing </p>
          </center>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.pdfToHTML}>Download PDF</button>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

Javascript with HTML: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVuHr-Q7HEs

Comment: `<div classID="HTMLtoPDF">` ? Shouldn't it be `<div id="HTMLtoPDF">`

Comment: thanks. it works. I thought classID and id are the same. But Why doesn't  classID work.?

Comment: The style is not showing up

Comment: @Longdo classID is the HTML attribute classid which applies to <Object> only, has nothing to do with CSS

Comment: Just to answer the question about why "classID" doesn't work... It's because "classID" doesn't exist. "class" is used when you want to select _multiple_ tags with the same distinction, whereas "id" is used when you only want to select _ONLY ONE_ thing. You must've mixed the two up to make "classID".

Comment: It seems that jsPDF package has deprecated fromHTML method and this solution is no longer of use.

Answer (score 5):

React don't have "classID" property in html tags, it's passed to div as props, which will never be resolved.
className was only implemented because it's reserved word in JS, perhabs you need to replace your "classID" by only "id" property and it will work

P.s. JQuery is bad practice when all what you need is DOM manipulation. javascript have document.getElementById() and dependency is not needed

P.p.s. small tip for you is "pdfToHTML(){}" can be replaced to lambda as "pdfToHTML = () => {}", and your function will have "this" from class instance, binding will be removed and constructor will become useless.

Comment: changing `classID` to `id` doesn't work. You get the following error:

`Error: addImage does not support files of type 'UNKNOWN', please ensure that a plugin for 'UNKNOWN' support is added.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `html2canvas` http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ and `jspdf` https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF libraries to create/download a PDF file from React Js like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017234/8339172

Here is a sample of using the `html2canvas` and `jspdf` libraries with the functional component:

```js
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

const App = () => {
  const printRef = React.useRef();

  const handleDownloadPdf = async () => {
    const element = printRef.current;
    const canvas = await html2canvas(element);
    const data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    const pdf = new jsPDF();
    const imgProperties = pdf.getImageProperties(data);
    const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
    const pdfHeight =
      (imgProperties.height * pdfWidth) / imgProperties.width;

    pdf.addImage(data, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
    pdf.save('print.pdf');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleDownloadPdf}>
        Download as PDF
      </button>

      <div>I will not be in the PDF.</div>
      <div ref={printRef}>I will be in the PDF.</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Reference: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-component-to-pdf/

Answer (score -1):

This is my way

```
- You can use that package in pure javascript file or server 
side(Backend)
- When you use it with the ReactJS(Frontend), it doesn't work.
- So I didn't use that.
- With html2canvas and jsPDF, I could build pdf.
- First build component, then save(download) it.
```