# Object not a function, on jspdf invocation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I have borrowed the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529149/create-pdf-file-from-html-text-react?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I am trying to make it work as a proof of concept in my React application.One of the issues I encounter is with line:

```
var pdf = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'letter');
```

In such case I get the following error: TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jspdf**.jspdf is not a constructor

If I remove 'new'
    var pdf = jspdf('p', 'pt', 'letter');

I am getting the error: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

What am I doing wrong. It seems like it is working in all examples, but no in my editor :)

Comment: what does `console.log(jspdf)` give?

Comment: is it possbile the script is not yet loaded, did you check for that

Comment: @Keith, nothing it breaks on the aforementioned command itself.

Comment: @Dellirium what do you mean?

Comment: Do you get -> `Uncaught ReferenceError: jspdf is not defined` by any chance?

Comment: No, and given @AthMav's comment below, I am surprised.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo

```
const jsPDF = require('jspdf')
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter')
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what I am missing here. This is the only way my app compiles, given I have a typo:
####
import {jsPDF} from 'jspdf';
....
var pdf = jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
####
but still it breaks like above(TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
)

Comment: No it didnt. I am getting an error saying: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function.

So I am in a place, where I cannot use it both as constructor and function?

Comment: Not sure why, I see it is used as constructor here: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/html2pdf/lists.html

Comment: I dont know.... try importing it from the html <script src="path/to/jspdf/"></script>

Comment: YESSS!! That worked. It was kinda obscure. Many thanks for the hint @AthMav :)

Comment: which did it? the one from github?
import * as jsPDF from jspdf?

Comment: the const jsPDF = require('jspdf') one. the  import * as jsPDF from jspdf was failing to compile