# React: open pdf document from a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I need to create a react component to open a pdf file. The pdf document will be opened through a link. I did some research and checked some posts on stackoverflow. e.g [Create PDF file from HTML text React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41529149/create-pdf-file-from-html-text-react)
But this one converts from `html` to `pdf` and what i need to do is just open a pdf document.

Is there any article or posts online that could help me?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: React has nothing to do with opening files. Search for the same thing without the "react" keyword and display the result in whatever <div> your React code renders.

Answer (score 0):

If the url of the pdf is not ["cross-origin"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) you could use the ["PDFJS"](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) library to render the PDF in the browser.